# watir-webdriver unable to find checkbox in headless firefox

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this checkbox on the page I am trying to drive using watir-webdriver

```
<input type="checkbox" name="company[active]" id="archived">
```

I have identified it using the id `status_id: "archived"`

and trying to set it with the code

```
    @b.checkbox(:id => @@locator[:status_id]).wait_until_present
    @b.checkbox(:id => @@locator[:status_id]).set
```

And I get the error

```
timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>"archived", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"checkbox"} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
```

Also tried with name attribute with same result

It works fine in firefox and phantomjs. This fails only in headless version of firefox

Headless firefox settings are

```
ENV DISPLAY=":99.0" \
FF_VERSION="42.0"
```

Did any face the same and were able to solve it?

Comment: you need to provide the webpage or a comparable example of the webpage for somebody to test out here, I think

Comment: Can you set your script to take a screenshot at the point of the error?  That is often a very illuminating thing to do. Your problem may be that the page is not fully rendered when the script wants to interact with the element, or else a mis-rendering of the page can cause the element to be obscured by another.